# ICS new datepicker not working

Tags: android, date, dialog, datepicker, timepicker

I have set android:targetSdkVersion=15 and build SDK to 15 as well assuming that app will use new nice datepicker from ICS and on 2.x devices it will use old nasty one.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Unfortunally it istn't working. Maybe I miss something, but according to API Demos, it should work. Where could be a problem?

EDIT: I have created sample project, where everything works fine, so maybe I need to clean or fix my project somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I am using old GreenDroid lib, which used theme that extended from android:Theme.Light, so I had to change theme to android:Theme.Holo.Light a everything seems ok now. Even on 2.x devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse you can go to Project-> properties -> then select android. From there you should be able to select the target API level. Also check the project.properties file to look for this line

Project target

target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8

the project.properties file is created automatically so modifying something there will not fix your issue but it may show you that its not trying for SDK 15

Comment: Not working at all. Why should I choose API target 8, when I want to make functional feature from newer API?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding that was just a piece out of my program. the min sdk version allows the android market to not display your app to devices running anything less than version 7. but if you are targeting version 15 you may be using things that are not available to a device running 7

Comment: Sure, I know about it. Thats it, why I use Lint to check these problems before release.

Comment: I see you got it working but could you link the tutorial you were following?